# Structural subtyping equivalence in Typescript

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

In the function below, an object is being returned in the first function which typescript compiler complains about. While for the second function it doesnt complain. Why this difference?

```
    type  x = {
    name:string
}
type r = {
    name:string,
    age:number
}
//Invalid
function returnSomething():x{
  return {
      name:"abc",
      age:12
  }
}
//Valid
function returnSomething():x{
        let z:r ={
        name:"abc",
        age:12
    }
    return z
}
console.log(returnSomething())
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are only done when directly returning an object literal, not when returning a variable.